# After making revisions, why can I only select the initially submitted manuscript in the system?

Tags: mathematics, springer

After revising the submission version for Springer, the generated file (pdf) still appears to be the original initial draft.

Recently, I have completed revisions for my article (Bulletin of the Malaysian Mathematical Sciences Society（Springer) and I'm prepared to submit the revised version. However, after making revisions,  I encountered the issue shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

The system is requiring me to select this option (Include in Revision); otherwise, I cannot proceed to approve the final modifications.

However, when I do select it, the system generates a pdf file that is still the original manuscript rather than the revised version. **In this system, other newly uploaded files cannot be choosed as the **manuscript**.**

[image]

[image]

I can only submit the revised version as supplementary material and not as the new main manuscript.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Is this issue due to the system's functionality? I'm unsure whether the editors and reviewers can see my revised materials.

Comment: I know the reason now; only the LaTeX file (not pdf) can be selected as the new manuscript.